# Precompiling (creating a mapping?) EF DbContext for faster debugging

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

It takes a while (3 minutes+) to 'create/compile' my DbContext. The web server starts in about 5 seconds, but when I do the first query to my database, Entity Framework has to 'build/create/compile' the database in memory or something, I think? The next requests are almost instant. This was a Database First creation of the DbContext, the database already exists in MSSQL and has data. The DbContext contains about 500 DbSet's with relations.

Is there a way to speed this up by doing the 'creation(mapping?)' of my Entity Framework's DbContext before running the web server, create the file/mappings it needs, so the first request is fast too?

EDIT1:

I've tried the Power Tools, but they give me an error that the DbContext has no constructor that can be used, while it has a normal constructor

```
public DbContext() : base() {}
```

Any other things I could try?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework documentation describes how to generate views using EF Power Tool [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601).

Once you have in stalled EF Power Tools you have to:

1. Right click on the class containing your DbContext or on your `.edmx` file
2. Select "Generate Views"

This will generate the class containing the pre-computed mapping, which will automatically load on startup. If you change your database and don't regenerate the views EF will throw an exception.

Whether it will work for EF7 though, who knows...

Comment: That is exactly why I ask this, I'm using EF7 RC1. I've read that part of the documentation already before asking the question. Also, because I work in an 'Enterprise' according to the licensing of VS, I'm using VS Express, which means I can't install any extensions...

Comment: Then it sounds like you'll have to use the manual method listed on that page, which presumably still works? Honestly, I doubt anybody has made a custom solution for this problem when an extension exists for the vast majority of people :(